# create string for string seen in FullForm

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation, text, named-characters, text-formatting

Can we create a string for *a string seen in FullForm* ?

This question is hard to explain/understand with just words.

So explain with an example :

Can you create a function `F1`, such that
if `str1 = "\[Alpha]\r\n\[Bullet]"`,
then `F1[str1]` becomes

```
{"\\", "[", "A", "l", "p", "h", "a", "]", "\\", "r", "\\", "n", "\\", \
    "[", "B", "u", "l", "l", "e", "t", "]"}
```

Related screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
F1 = Characters[ToString[FullForm[#]]][[2;;-2]]&;
```

Comment: Thank you, one can use this to auto-correct full-path of folder or file. I'll add it in my post.